# Pichia pastoris and ornithine

Tags: biotechnology, yeast, recombinant

Can Pichia pastoris (species of yeast used for recombinant protein) produce the non-protein amino acid Ornithine? Or does it express ornithine at all?

Comment: is the pichia pastoris genome available from some sequence database? you could search for ornithine synthetic genes

Comment: yes, i can look for the pichia pastoris genome sequence on NCBI. do you suggest that i compare the genome sequence of pichia and ornithine and see if there is a match between them ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it contains [arginase](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/?term=pichia%20pastoris%20arginase). Thise enzyme converts [arginine to ornithine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithine#Role_in_urea_cycle) and is probably part of the urea cycle.

You might notice the arginase is listed as coming from Komagataella phaffii GS115, but this is just another (new?) name for Pichia.